# How to transfer deployment package from S3 to EC2 instance to run python script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitlab-ci

**AWS beginner here**

I have a repo in GitLab which has a python script and a `requirements.txt` file, and the python script has to be deployed in the EC2 ubuntu instance (and the script has to be triggered only once a day) via Gitlab CI. I am creating a deployment package of the repo using CI and through this, I am deploying the zipped package in the S3 bucket. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: ubuntu:18.04

variables:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: eu-central-1
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    S3_TEST_BUCKET: $BUCKET_UNPACK

stages:
    - deploy 

TestJob:
    stage: deploy
    script:
    - apt-get -y update
    - apt-get -y install python3-pip python3.7 zip
    - python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
    - python3.7 -V
    - pip3.7 install virtualenv
    - mv iso_forest_ad.py ~ # This is the python script
    - mv requirements.txt ~

    # Setup virtual environment
    - mkdir ~/forEC2
    - cd ~/forEC2
    - virtualenv -p python3 venv
    - source venv/bin/activate
    - pip3.7 install -r ~/requirements.txt -t ~/forEC2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

    # Package environment and dependencies
    - cd ~/forEC2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
    - zip -r9 ~/forEC2/archive.zip .
    - cd ~
    - zip -g ~/forEC2/archive.zip iso_forest_ad.py

    - pip install awscli --upgrade
    - export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_TEST_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_TEST_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - aws configure set default.region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
    - aws s3 cp ~/forEC2/archive.zip $BUCKET_UNPACK/anomaly-detection-deployment.zip
```

Contents of `requirements.txt`

```
-i https://pypi.org/simple
joblib==0.16.0; python_version >= '3.6'
numpy==1.19.0
pandas==1.0.5
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
python-dateutil==2.8.1; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3'
pytz==2020.1
scikit-learn==0.23.1
scipy==1.5.1; python_version >= '3.6'
six==1.15.0; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3'
sqlalchemy==1.3.18
threadpoolctl==2.1.0; python_version >= '3.5'
```

Now, I would like to transfer the script and install the dependencies in the ubuntu EC2 instance and run the script.

I know one way would be to connect to the EC2 instance and do

```
aws s3 sync s3://s3-bucket-name/folder /home/ubuntu
```

as suggested in the post: [Moving files from s3 to EC2 instance](https://optimalbi.com/aws-tips-and-tricks-moving-files-from-s3-to-ec2-instance/). But doing this, I was not able to install the dependencies from the `requirements.txt` file.

I would like to know if there is an alternate way (perhaps maybe by using shell script or some other way?) for achieving this. Since I am using ubuntu locally too, using putty is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://optimalbi.com/aws-tips-and-tricks-moving-files-from-s3-to-ec2-instance/) you've posted **already shows** one way of doing this. Namely, by using [UserData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

Therefore, you would have to develop a **bash script** which would not only download the zip file as shown in the link, but also unpack it, and install the `requirements.txt` file along side with any other dependencies or configuration setup you require.

So the `UserData` for your instance would be something like this (pseudo-code, this is only a rough example):

```
#!/bin/bash 

apt update
apt install -y zip awscli python3-pip # awscli is not normally on ubuntu

aws s3 sync s3://optimal-aws-nz-play-config/package.zip .

unzip package.zip

cd package

pip install -r ./requirenements.txt
```

If this is something you do often, you could create **lunch template** with the instance settings and the `UserData` to automatically execute these steps for each instance launched from the template.

There are also other possibilities, involving `CodeDeploy`, `CodePipeline`, but plain old `UserData` would be a good start.

Alternative would be to use [run-command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html). The execution of the command would be triggered from gitlab following upload of the new s3 package.

An example of how to invoke the run-command is in the [docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html):

```
aws ssm send-command \
    --document-name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" \
    --parameters commands=["echo helloWorld"] \
    --targets Key=tag:Env,Values=Dev,Test
```

Instead of `echo helloWorld` you would have to write your own bash commands to be executed.

Comment: Hey, @Marcin, thank you for your reply. I read that the `UserData` is run only once when the instance is created. If yes, considering the scenario that I made changes to my script and I want those changes to be deployed, what would happen in that case?

Comment: @reinhardt Hi. Sadly, nothing. UserData runs only once. If you want to have your script deployed each time you make changes, you can use  CodePipeline for that as mentioned in the answer. Also you could use [RunCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) which would be easier to use. Basically, in your gitlab.yml, you would use aws cli to execute run command on your instances. the command would run script which does basically same what userdata does.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you, if possible, add a small example of using the run command?

Comment: @reinhardt Example added :-)